# Granting ASP.NET access to download file from sharepoint website

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5

I have an ASP.NET application which I am testing on the ASP.NET Development server. The application is meant to download a file from an intranet sharepoint site. I am using `WebClient.DownloadFile()` for this purpose. But I am getting the following exception-

> "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

The account with which I am logged into Windows while running the application has access to the resource which I want to download.

I tried ro run the application on `IIS 7.5` as well, giving the application pool the required identity to download the file. But still got the same error.

Any idea what exactly is the problem and how to overcome it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem got resolved by setting *UseDefaultCredentials* property of the WebClient to true

Answer (score 2):

It's a problem with double hop delegation. Look at this: http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2008/08/22/iis-windows-authentication-and-the-double-hop-issue.aspx

Comment: +1... could not remember the "double hop delegation" name :) I like "one hop NTLM hell" more...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming normal Windows (NTLM) authentication on SharePoint site.

Most likley you are hitting by design behavior "double hop delegation" sometimes called "one hop NTLM hell" - credentials passed from client (browser) to server (your ASP.Net application) can't be used outside of the box. As result your ASP.Net application autorizes as more or less anonymous user and can't authorize on SharePoint site.

Common way to solve it - have some sort of trusted account and run your site's code under that account. Than when accessing the site you run code under process' account (not impersonating the user). You'll need to review code to have reasonable security measures as bugs will allow anyone use your site to access SharePoint/other resources under that special account.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Kerberos issue, as Kirill mentioned. Before you start setting SPNs and the like, please follow the advice on [this link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/proclarity/archive/2011/03/08/useapppoolcredentials-true-with-kerberos-delegation-on-2008.aspx) first.

I recently had a frustrating week of trying to get Kerberos to work on a locked down domain and at the end of it all I found all I had to do was set useAppPoolCredentials to true.

If that doesn't help, [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4754) provided quite useful to me as well.

Good luck!